# Saving Gson's JsonObject to mongoDB as plain Json without Members object

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, gson, mongotemplate

I am using Gson Library to convert JsonString to JsonObject and save it to MongoDB. I am using springboot application with mongoDB and my expected result is to save as plain Json Object in the data base directly.

**Expected:**

```
    {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "FirstName",
  "data": {
    "dataArrayObject": {
      "ItemName": "Item1"
    }
  }
}
```

While saving to DB its saving as below

**Actual:**

```
      {
  "members": {
    "id": {
      "value": 1,
      "_class": "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive"
    }
  },
  "members": {
    "name": {
      "value": "FirstName",
      "_class": "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive"
    }
  },
  "dataArrayObject": {
    "members": {
      "ItemName": {
        "value": "Item1",
        "_class": "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive"
      },
       "_class": "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide your save data code

Comment: mongoTemplate.insert(jsonObject, COLLECTION_NAME);

Comment: Try to save plain JSON string

Comment: My requirement is to save as JSON in DB Directly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. After I converted to string using `toString()` method, I got the expected json in mongodb.

```
 mongoTemplate.save("collectionName", jsonObject.toString());
```